# Excel multiple columns filter in c# interop

Tags: c#, excel-interop, jagged-arrays

I have two excel sheets in the same file each containing 5 columns. Data in my first excel sheet are unique. While the second sheet can contain duplicates. I'm filtering and comparing each record in first sheet with all the records in second sheet. Data in first sheet lasts in a few hundreds records, but data in second sheet is pretty large, say 200k-300k. Manual comparison by filtering data makes this time consuming.

**Problem:** I am trying to automate this `multiple column filter` criteria of excel in c# `WinForms`.

**What I tried:** I thought Jagged Arrays would do the trick so created two `Jagged Arrays`. Each jagged array is populated dynamically with data of 1 sheet. So `JaggedAry1` will contain data from `Sheet1` and `JaggedAry2` of `Sheet2`. If I'm not wrong, Probably the jagged arrays would look something like this:

> JaggedAry1:

```
Row 1           Name   Jim   Bob   Joe    
Row 2           Age    25    30    35
Row 3           ID     1AB   2C    2BE
Row 4           Addr   Ad1   Ad2   Ad3
Row 5           DOB    D1    D2    D3
```

> JaggedAry2:

```
Row 1           Name   Jim   Bob   Joe    Jim   Bob   Jim    Joe   Bob   Sam    
Row 2           Age    25    30    35     25    32    35     25    30    35
Row 3           ID     1AB   2C    2BE    1AB   2C    2D     AB    2W    2E
Row 4           Addr   Ad1   Ad2   Ad3    Ad1   Ad2   Ad4    Ad5   Ad6   Ad7
Row 5           DOB    D1    D2    D3     D1    D2    D3     D3    D4    D5
```

**Example Result:** If I have two organization's data, Jim can be name of multiple persons and can have the same ID's. If in `sheet1`, I have an employee name Jim whose DOB is on Jan 25th 1988 and with ID=2, than, in `sheet2` I want to list all the Jim's whose DOB will be on or after Jan 25th 1988, with same ID's i.e., ID=2. Address can be same or different.

I know I can do this with `foreach` loops, but I think that will take a lot of temporary variables for multiple comparisons. So I thought if there could be an easier way?

**Note**: I also tried to directly apply filter on the second sheet using `Range Filter` of InteropExcel. But this works fast only for small amounts of data. Excel files with large amounts of data makes it time consuming.

It would be really great if someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in anyways with 200k-300k lines we'll have time consuming to read....

Answer (score 0):

so Excel has its limits, with 300k lines, maybe it will be interesting to migrate to sql Database.

But if you dont plan this solution and keep Excel, i suggest you to use [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) to read your large excel file and work with Linq/LinqToSql to filter your data. ExcelDataReader is very fine to read fastly large file.

In second approach, either you have the memory to load the whole data, you could work on it after loading.. if not, no other solution to test each item before load what you want to keep